# C# / MongoDB : How do I keep a connection alive?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, visual-studio, database

I'm writing a C# application which accesses a remote MongoDB. How do I go about persisting the connection while I query the database? Should I implement some sort of open/close mechanism? Or would it be better to connect once and have a time-out? I'm usign the official MongoDB / C# driver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the hood the MongoDB C# driver maintains a connection pool, which is fairly typical in .NET.  The pool works by maintaining a number of open connections for you.  When you need a connection the pool will give you an existing connection (provided one is available).

The issue to avoid is a leak in your connections--if connections are opened and not closed again then you will undermine the gains of the connection pool and will need to open an additional connection every time.  Also, if there is a connection leak, there's the chance it will consume extra resources on your client as well as the server.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, just one question: what happens when you don't close a connection? Do they eventually time-out?

Comment: If a connection remains open and is never garbage collected then it will remain idle in the background and never be freed.  Often times you'll get lucky and connections you don't explicitly close will be cleaned up--however after you get burned a couple times by leaks you'll be more careful to ensure things get closed, disposed, and garbage collected.  Lingering objects are by far the most common cause of resource leaks in .NET

Comment: in a nutshell: `using` and `try/catch/finally` are your friends

Comment: I know this is an old question but i do not see anywhere the use of IDisposable in the driver, so how would i close connections @STW?